# Laravel create GUID for specific column

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a UUID/GUID for a specific column in Laravel 5. So i am using the Library from Webpatser to get an UUID in Laravel5.

I would like to set this as default for a specific column, so i guess i should use attributes, or?

But when i use

```
protected $attributes = array('guid' => Uuid::generate(4)->string);
```

ill always get an error with:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

I am not sure, because the syntax looks fine and when ill try

```
protected $attributes = array('guid' => 'dsadasfasfsaf');
```

Everything works fine (guid is a varchar(36) field) - and

```
Uuid::generate(4)->string
```

returns a string.

Do i need anything else to create a default value for my model? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can't parse non-trivial expressions in initializers.

You can do this:

```
class YourClass 
{
    protected $attributes;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->attributes = array('guid' => Uuid::generate(4)->string);
    }
}
```

Or this by using the setter method:

```
class YourClass 
{
    protected $attributes;

    public function setAttributes($attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
    }
}

$classInstance = new YourClass;
$classInstance->setAttributes(array('guid' => Uuid::generate(4)->string));
```

Comment: Thanks! If ill use the Constructor, the GUID is now fine, but could this be a Problem because my Mutators would not be called anymore?

Answer (score 0):

$identifier = WebpatserUuidUuid::generate(4)->string;